# unable to resolve class org.apache.shiro.grails.ConfigUtils

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, shiro

I've upgraded my grails shiro plugin and now get the following error:

unable to resolve class org.apache.shiro.grails.ConfigUtils

using grails 2.4.3 with shiro plugin: 1.2.1

I'm guessing ConfigUtils has been deprecated at some point but I've been unable to find a guide that describes what I need to do with the latest Shiro.

I found the following in the Shiro plugin source:

security.shiro.filter.config option is deprecated. Use Grails' bean property override mechanism instead.

But I have no explanation to what this means.

Answer (score 1):

Using (this)[http://docs.grails.org/2.4.3/guide/spring.html#propertyOverrideConfiguration] as a template, maybe something like this:

```
security {
    shiro {
        plugin {
            config {
                myKey = "myValue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have only used things like this to inject values into controllers and strings, not to set config parameters, the pattern fits however.